# Can't Open Microphone Error when using an Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-edittext, android-speech-api

I am creating an app that using google's api for converting speech to text.  The following code works perfectly when I have it set as the main activity.  However I am now creating a new app and have copy pasted the xml layout and java file as an activity called `display_1`.  My issue now is when I navigate to this window through the app, I expect voice recognition to begin after 500ms and it in fact does but I get a message saying 'Can't open Microphone'.

I have added the correct permissions into the gradle file and have set the correct min API level. Please not my main activity for the app uses PocketSphinx sdk and then this second activity called `display_1` uses google api which implements `onClickListener`

If someone can tell me what is causing me to get the 'Can't Open Microphone' warning that will be appreciated.  Please note wifi etc are connected.  Below is the java file:

```
public class Display_1 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

ListView lv;
static final int check = 1111;
Button b;
EditText a;
Button c;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_1);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvVoiceReturn_1);
    a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFusername_1);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bVoice_1);
    c = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Blogin_1);

    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    //This now handles an automatic press of the bVoice button 1 second after the activity is opened
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            b.callOnClick();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Blogin_1) {
        String str = a.getText().toString();


        //Go to the relevant page if any part of the phrase or word entered in the 'EditText' field contains 'next' which is not case sensitive
        if (str.toLowerCase().contains("next")) {
            Intent userintent = new Intent(Display_1.this, Display_2.class);
            startActivity(userintent);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Please Repeat Again");
    startActivityForResult(i, check);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));

        a.setText((String) lv.getItemAtPosition(0));    //Get the first phrase in the first row of list view

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                c.performClick();
            }
        }, 500);    //Automatically click the 'Blogin' button after 500ms
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

The following are the permission I have set in the android manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Comment: I got the same error. but It was cause I had started recording audio using another thread with AudioRecord class. Silly me! make sure u didnt do it too!